# Unit testing a GORM call with a closure

Tags: unit-testing, grails, closures, spock

I have a Grails service that does a `where` query like this:

```
List<Car> search(Long makeId = null) {
    Car.where {
        join("make")
        if(makeId) {
            make.id == makeId
        }
    }.findAll()
}
```

I'm trying to unit test it with Spock like this:

```
def setup() {
    GroovyMock(Car, global: true)
}

void "test search"() {
    when:
        service.search()
    then:
        1 * Car.where {}
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to test the content of the closure.

I can get the test to pass by verifying `1 * Car.where(_)`, but how can I make assertions on the content of the closure, i.e. that `join` was called and that the `make.id` constraint is specified only when needed?

Comment: My preference would be to test the search method instead.

In the spec, you would setup data that get returned only if the makeId is specified. So with two 'when / then' blocks, you can test that providing/not providing makeId works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the closure's delegate to be an Mock of DetachedCriteria to make assertions on it. DetachedCriteria is the main class used in gorm to build the query.

Example:

```
given: 'Mocking DetachedCriteria'
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteriaMock = Mock(DetachedCriteria)
and: 'Just to avoid nullPointerException when findAll() call happens on service'
1 * detachedCriteriaMock.iterator() >> [].listIterator()
when:
service.search(1L)
then:
// Capture the argument
1 * Car.where(_) >>  { args ->
    args[0].delegate = detachedCriteriaMock
    args[0].call()

    return detachedCriteriaMock
}

// Join is a method on detached criteria
1 * detachedCriteriaMock.join('make')
// Make is an association, so detachedCriteria uses the methodMissing to find the property.
// In this case, we call the closure setting the delegate to the mock
1 * detachedCriteriaMock.methodMissing('make', _) >> { args ->
    // args[1] is the list of arguments.
    // args[1][0] is the closure itself passed to detachedCriteria
    args[1][0].delegate = detachedCriteriaMock
    args[1][0].call()
}
// If id is passed, it must compare (eq method) with value 1
1 * detachedCriteriaMock.eq('id', 1L)
```

Comment: That works great for testing the `join` call, can I use it to test the `make.id` constraint as well?

Comment: Yes! But in this case you want to test the interaction with 'make' call method. So you have to use mocks! I did some refactoring on my example code. Hope it helps.

Comment: It sure helps, i get what you're doing here, but with your code i'm getting a `MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.Expando.make() is applicable for argument types [_closure stuff]`...what am I missing?

Comment: Very strange. It's look like that test code is not using the Expando Mock. Or the code is calling the real implementation or you can try to change the `1 * joinCallMock.getProperty('make') >> makeCallMock` to `1 * joinCallMock.invokeMethod('make', []) >> makeCallMock` since it's look like that make is not a property but a method.

Comment: Yep I thought about that and I already tried using `invokeMethod`, but it throws the same exception :(

Comment: What version of gorm are you using? I'm gonna run the test code to see the problem.

Comment: `org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.4.RELEASE`

Comment: @Raibaz Wow, finally. The error you mentioned was related to transaction that grails provide on unit/integration test. So I have to change the mock to the class expected on the transaction code. Hope it helps! Maybe its easier to create an integration test in this situation.

Comment: Yep in the end i did it with an integration test, but still thanks a lot for the clarifications :)